# Magento 2 - New coupon code not working in cart page

Tags: magento2, coupon

Magento 2 coupon code are saved in cart while changed new coupon code still shows the old coupon code how to fix this issue?

Comment: does the new coupon code genrated successfully?and what are their upc?

Comment: yes i have changed new coupon code for existing rule again i have refersh the page in website still old coupon code only shows in apply coupon field

Comment: run php bin/magento c:f  and php bin/magento c:c then try to reproduce this on the incognito browser to confirm that it isn't cache issue.

Comment: Tried its not a cache issue old one saved

Comment: screenshort or step to reproduce will help to reproduce or understand this issue.